# Default style for TextBlock not being picked up after applying a style key

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `<ResourceDictionary>` containing this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="..\..\Fonts\#Roboto"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
</Style>
```

This works fine.

Now I've added another style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyText" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
</Style>
```

However, after changing my `<TextBlock>` to `<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MyText}"/>` - only the styles within the 2nd style block are picked up. E.g. the `FontFamily`, `FontSize` and `TextWrapping` are now ignored.

How can I have a default for a `TextBlock`, and then add to it? I don't want to add an `x:Key` to the 'default' style as this is in use throughout the system already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to base your keyed style on the type.  See example below.

Note the `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MyText" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MyAppendedStyles" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MyText}" Text="Style Key" />
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MyAppendedStyles}" Text="Style Key" />
</StackPanel>
```